# Chain of Transmission between Nachum and Rabbi Meyasha

Tags: rambam, mesorah-tradition, tannaim, masechet-peah

In the [Mishnah Peah 2:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Peah.2.6?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he), the text seems to suggest that Nachum the scribe received teachings **from** Rabbi Meyasha:

> "אָמַר נַחוּם הַלַּבְלָר, מְקֻבָּל אֲנִי מֵרַבִּי מְיָאשָׁא שקבל מאבא,
> ..."

However, the [Rambam](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_(%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%96%D7%99)) (decending) lists the order differently, placing Nachum the Scribe **before** Rabbi Meyasha:

> "רבי עקיבא. רבי חוצפית. רבי נתן. נחום הלבלר. רבי מיאשא."

Additionally. Who is אבא in our Mishna?

Comment: ולא שמרנו בזכרון שמותם סדר זמניהם

Comment: [The Kuzari](https://www.sefaria.org/Kuzari.3.67?vhe=Yehudah_Even_Shmuel,_1973&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) seems to say the same as the Mishnah

Comment: @Shmuel Im not seeing the Kuzari chain for  רבי מיאשא, can you quote it here? (I only see him quoting the Mishna)

Comment: That's correct. He seems to acknowledge it

Comment: @shmosel didn't realize you were quoting the Rambam. 1)What does that mean? In this case we have a explicit Mishna?

Answer (score 2):

A: The Rambam you quoted is not in order of when they lived. For example it has Reb Eliezer the son of Reb Yossi Hagleli and then around 30 names later Reb Yossi Hagleli. Clearly the list is not in order of years. Later the Rambam has a list of genorations which he lists רב מיאשא as generation six and Nachum the scribe in generation seven. Clearly therefore according to the Rambam this works with the Mishnah in Peah.

> והחבורה הששית עקביא בן מהללאל ושמעיה ואבטליון וחנן ואדמון ורבי מיאשא.
> והחבורה השביעית שמאי והלל ומנחם ויהודה בן בתירה ורבי פפאיס ורבי יוחנן
> בן בג בג וחנניה בן חזקיה בן גרון ונחוניא בן הקנה ובבא בן בוטא ורבי
> יוחנן בן החורוני ורבן גמליאל הזקן ונחום הלבלר

B: Who was אבא mentioned in the Mishna? It would seem either אביו which would be his father or a different ‘tanna’ called Aba which lived at the time of Shammi and Hillel

Here is a quote from the sefer תולדות תנאים ואמורים which goes through who lived when.

> אבא (תנא בזמן הנית).  נזכר פאה פ"ב מ"ו מעשה שזרע ר"ש איש המצפה [ובא]
> לפני ‏ רבן גמליאל [הזקן] ‏ ועלו ללשכת הגזית ושאלו, אמר נחום הלבלר
> מקובל אני מר' מיאשא שקבל "מאבא" שקבל מזוגות,  ולפי סדר. הזמנים היה אבא
> זה תלמיד דהלל ושמאי שהיו סוף הזוגות וכן פירש"י ותום' בנזיר נ"ו אך יש
> גורסין שקבל מאביו" - וכן הוא בפי' הרא"ש בנזיר נ"ו: וביוחסין מאמר ראשון
> ערך ר' ישמעאל מביא מתוספתא ביצה פ"ג וז"ל ‏ אמרו עליו על ר' אבא ור'
> אלעזר ב"ר צדוק ועל אבא שאול בן בטנית שהיו חנונים בירושלים, ‏ ואם נקים
> גרסתו (כי בתוספתא שלגז ליתא תיבת ר' אבא), הוא אבא זה הנזכר בפאה כמו
> שבארנו בערך ר"א בר צדוק שהוא אביו דר' צדוק שהיה בחורבן ור"א זה היה
> בזמן. ר"ג הזקן.

Comment: I think you are mistaking the Amora (רבי מיאשה בר בריה דרבי יהושע בן לוי) With the Tanna רַבִּי מְיָאשָׁא

Comment: true... edited.